# Scheduling: How to remove slurm cloud nodes from existing without marking them as down?

Tags: slurm

**Current behavior**

When a new instance is started by `slurm`, that instance is listed as a cloud node in `sinfo`. Sometimes we don't want to wait until `slurm` terminates the instance (after `SuspendTime`) and "releases" the node (so a new instance can claim that nodes place), but want to terminate an instance and "release" the node manually. The only way we know of currently is: 0) Terminate the instance I) Set the node state to down `sudo scontrol update NodeName=$NODE_NAME state=DOWN reason=NoReason` wait until it is no longer shown in `sinfo` and resume the node `sudo scontrol update NodeName=$NODE_NAME state=RESUME reason=NoReason`. After that the node can be used by slurm again.

However this is not really a good solution since you still have to wait quite some time.

**Wanted behavior**

After terminating the instance manually I would like to call a command that instantly "releases" a node, allowing a new instance to take its name and place once it's needed.

**Why?**

For updating the master we don't want any active worker instances.

Comment: Hey, did figure out a solution ?

Comment: I've created an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use nowadays is:

```
sudo scontrol update NodeName=$NODE_NAME state=POWER_DOWN reason=NoNeed
```

However, while this answers the question there is a niche case that it may not solve. Nodes that failed during startup, will only be marked as `~idle` (not started idle) when the `ResumeTimeout` has run out. Tests indicated that the command above doesn't work during startup, but I am not entirely sure about that.

Comment: I see, I was doing this and the nodes remain unusable afterward. Today I tried the state FUTURE, but it does not help with me. That sucks.